# Three.js - BinaryLoader vs. BufferGeometry for large meshes?

Tags: three.js, webgl, mesh, buffer-geometry

I'm looking for a most efficient way to load large polygonal meshes (up to 1M triangles) to Three.js. I'm considering either using a `THREE.BufferGeometry` object or loading with `THREE.BinaryLoader`. My questions are:

- Does [BinaryLoader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/BinaryLoader.js) create a `THREE.BufferGeometry` object underneath? Or does it create something similarly efficient?
- If not, does anyone have a recommendation which one to use?

Some additional info:

- My models are in a proprietary format on the server, so I need to convert/encode them anyway.
- I haven't found a Three.js loader that creates a `THREE.BufferGeometry`. It looks like I need to write my own. But I can prepare the data on the server side to be aligned with `THREE.BufferGeometry` structure.
- [BinaryLoader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/BinaryLoader.js) provides all necessary infrastructure for loading data, but requires data to be prepared in a special way on the server side.

Comment: The CTMLoader creates BufferGeometry when instructed by the parameters argument `useBuffers: true`

Comment: @gaitat - thanks! That brings another option to the table. Is OpenCTM still under development? I've seen no updates for last 15+ months. Another alternative could by [webgl-loader](https://code.google.com/p/webgl-loader/), though I'm not sure if Three.js support is still up to date. I wish I have time to compare all those alternatives...

Comment: I think OpenCTM has done what it was supposed to, so no need for updates. The webgl-loader is also implemented inside three.js in the `UTF8Loader()` and also supports BufferGeometry with the same parameter. Additionally OpenCTM supports WebWorkers.

Comment: @gaitat - thanks again! I'll try both and post the results.

Comment: If some comment was useful, I would appreciate an up vote (left of comment)

Comment: @gaitat - I'll be happy to, just not sure how to vote up a comment. Perhaps you can edit it as an answer and I'll accept it (if I can).

Comment: Up arrow on the left of the comment. You have to move your mouse there to see the arrows.

Comment: hmmm, don't see any arrows for comments, only for the question (Safari on MacOS)

Comment: Simon probably had insufficient reputation to upvote your comment. I've just upvoted you both...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at glTF format and glTFLoader for Three.js. It uses BufferGeometry.
Performance is much better; however, it has its own animations implemented (doesn't use THREE.Animation) and I've ran into a few Three.js related problems like cloning the model won't work (at least out of the box)

glTF: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF

glTFLoader: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/54a1e789c3a84557d6b05782f5cbd9f1064f5e4f/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js